# Who is the lord in Mark 11:3?

Tags: mark

In Mark 11, Jesus tells his disciples to fetch a colt and explain to anyone who asks about it that the Lord (ὁ κύριος) needs it:

> As they approached Jerusalem and came to Bethphage and Bethany at the Mount of Olives, Jesus sent two of his disciples, saying to them, “Go to the village ahead of you, and just as you enter it, you will find a colt tied there, which no one has ever ridden. Untie it and bring it here. If anyone asks you, ‘Why are you doing this?’ say, ‘**The Lord** needs it and will send it back here shortly.’”
>
> Mark 11:1-3 NIV (emphasis mine)

Who is the referant of the word translated "Lord" here? Is Jesus referring to himself? To God? To someone else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question. My sense is that to get a fully satisfactory answer, Mark's version ought to be read beside the other accounts in the Synoptics (Matthew, Luke). (Those interested can read them, with the addition of John, in [English and Greek](http://goo.gl/IGRzGo) at BibleGateway.)

For Mark 11:3, the parallels work this way (n.b.: although John has a version of the "Triumphal Entry" story in John 12:12-19, it does not include the details about arrangements for the donkey):

> **Matthew** 21:3 "And if anyone says something to you, you shall say, '**The Lord** has need of them,' and immediately he will send them."
>   Matthew 21:3 καὶ ἐάν τις ὑμῖν εἴπῃ τι, ἐρεῖτε ὅτι **ὁ κύριος** αὐτῶν χρείαν ἔχει· εὐθὺς δὲ ἀποστελεῖ αὐτούς.
>
> **Mark** 11:3 "And if anyone says to you, 'Why are you doing this?' you say, '**The Lord** has need of it'; and immediately he will send it back here."
>   Mark 11:3 καὶ ἐάν τις ὑμῖν εἴπῃ· τί ποιεῖτε τοῦτο; εἴπατε· **ὁ κύριος** αὐτοῦ χρείαν ἔχει, καὶ εὐθὺς αὐτὸν ἀποστέλλει πάλιν ὧδε.
>
> **Luke** 19:31 "And if anyone asks you, 'Why are you untying it?' thus shall you speak, '**The Lord** has need of it.'"
>   Luke 19:31 καὶ ἐάν τις ὑμᾶς ἐρωτᾷ· διὰ τί λύετε; οὕτως ἐρεῖτε· ὅτι **ὁ κύριος** αὐτοῦ χρείαν ἔχει.

As OP's question suggests, there are essentially three options for the referent of "the [L/l]ord" here:

1. Jesus himself; or
2. God; or
3. someone else, with that "someone" being the owner of the animal.

The answer depends, in part, on the wider usage of ὁ κύριος (*ho kurios* = "the [L/l]ord") in these books, and in this context. The Synoptic gospels (Matthew // Mark // Luke) show different patterns in this regard. This is how the word "*kurios*" appears in the gospels:

```
+----+---------+---------+
|    |  with   |   no    |
|    | article | article |
+----+---------+---------+
| Mt |     26  |     54  |
| Mk |      6  |     12  |
| Lk |     45  |     59  |
| Jn |     16  |     36  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

It can be seen at once that Mark uses κύριος, whether with or without the article ("articular" or "anarthrous", respectively) far less often than Matthew and Luke.

**Matthew** appears to present the clearest case. A survey of occurrences bears out the claim of R.T. France that:<sup>1</sup>

> "the Lord" as a title in this gospel elsewhere always refers to Yahweh, never to Jesus. ... The password means simple "God needs them".

In **Luke**, matters are less clear. ὁ κύριος is regularly used with reference to Jesus, and its precise force in Lk 19:31 is debated. I.H. Marshall notes that "The word κύριος is ambiguous", suggesting that reference to God is unlikely, the "owner" more likely, but holding open the possibility (hence the ambiguity) that hearers could understand Jesus to be, in some sense, the "owner". In view of Lk 19:33, however (a second reference to the owner), Marshall opts for the animal's owner as the most likely reference.<sup>2</sup> Nolland, by contrast, presses the ambiguity:<sup>3</sup>

> To Luke and to his readers "the Lord" here is the "Lord" of the full Christian affirmation (cf. at 7:13), though in Luke's story line, the terminology need mean no more than "the master" (of the disciples) whose authority, nonetheless, comes with his disciples, who speak the words that have been given to them by their master.

Which brings us, then, to **Mark** with its much smaller frequency of occurrences of the key term in question. All three possible referents have their advocates among interpreters of this gospel. The conundrum appears to be that ὁ κύριος (that is, the articular use: "**the** Lord") tends to be restricted, in Mark, to God: e.g. at Mark 5:19, where all are agreed it *must* refer to God.

Commentators seem reluctant to see this force applied in this (11:3) context, however. Gould, who is adamant that 5:19 must refer to God, takes quite a different line in 11:3, arguing that in view of its "frequent application" to Jesus, here it is simply a self-reference: Jesus is "the Master" (of the disciples who speak for him).<sup>4</sup> Cranfield acknowledges that this is a common interpretation, but himself argues that in Mark's gospel, such a *self*-designation here comes too soon. He thinks reference to the *owner* makes more contextual sense (setting aside, then, reference to God).<sup>5</sup>

Anderson, by contrast, argues that this is precisely a unique case in Mark (thus acknowledging the common usage of ὁ κύριος), and asserts that we are

> in a context in which the supreme authority of Jesus over all things is highlighted

so that for

> the later Church the title 'Lord' with all that it implies is particularly appropriate.<sup>6</sup>

**Conclusion**

So, to whom **does** *ho kurios* refer in Mark 11:3? To my own mind, Cranfield and Lane make the more compelling observations, and the reference is most likely to the the animal's owner.

- the instruction (or "pass phrase") is for *anyone* they might encounter, and not for the animal's owner;
- Jesus' self-reference in [Mark 14:14](http://biblehub.com/mark/14-14.htm) is "the teacher"; but
- the ambiguity remains, and later readers can feel a resonance with a different "Lord" (thus the typical caplitalization in most modern English versions).

However (!), there is no knock-down argument here, and as a survey of commentators suggests, the other options have been defended by careful readers of the text.

---

*Notes*

1. R.T. France, *[The Gospel of Matthew](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080282501X)* (NICNT; Eerdmans, 2007), [p. 776](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0ruP6J_XPCEC&lpg=PR16&pg=PA776#v=onepage&q&f=false).
2. I.H. Marshall, *[The Gospel of Luke: A Commentary on the Greek Text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802835120)* (NIGTC; Eerdmans, 1978), p. 713.
3. John Nolland, *[Luke 18:35-24:53](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849910722)* (WBC, 35C; Word, 1993), p. 925.
4. E.P. Gould, *A Critical and Exegetical Commentary on the Gospel According to St. Mark* (ICC; T & T Clark, 1896), [p. 207](https://archive.org/stream/criticalexegetic27gouluoft#page/207/mode/1up).
5. C.E.B. Cranfield, *[The Gospel According to Saint Mark](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521092043)* (CUP, 1963), [pp. 349-50](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nqfx_EJMS38C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA349#v=onepage&q&f=false). W.L. Lane, *[The Gospel According to Mark](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802825028)* (NICNT; Eerdmans, 1974), [pp. 391-2, n. 3](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nIjPDDlweUgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA391#v=onepage&q&f=false) adopts a similar position, adding further considerations, especially the counter-example of Mark 14:13-14, which he thinks rules out the "self-reference" option.
6. H. Anderson, *[The Gospel of Mark](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=h8vYAAAAMAAJ)* (NCB; Marshall, Morgan & Scott/Eerdmans, 1976), p. 261.

Answer (score 1):

Who is the lord in Mark 11:3?

Lord refers to "Jesus" in fulfillment of Bible prophecy, Zechariah 9:9

As they approach Bethphage, on the Mount of Olives, Jesus tells two of his disciples:

Mark 11:2-3 (NASB)

> 2 "And *said to them, “Go into the village opposite you, and
>   immediately as you enter it, you will find a colt tied there, on which
>   no one yet has ever sat; untie it and bring it here. 3 If anyone says
>   to you, ‘Why are you doing this?’ you say, ‘The Lord has need of it’;
>   and immediately he [a]will send it back here.”

Jesus’ instructions involve Bible prophecy.  This is  in  the fulfillment of Zechariah’s prophecy that   foretold that God’s promised King would come into Jerusalem "Humble and mounted on a donkey, on a colt, the foal of a  donkey."

Zechariah's prophesy stated.

Zechariah 9:9  (NASB)

> 9 Rejoice greatly, O daughter of Zion! Shout in triumph, O daughter of
>   Jerusalem! Behold, your king is coming to you; He is just and endowed
>   with salvation, Humble, and mounted on a donkey,  Even on a colt, the
>   foal of a donkey.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that Jesus is referring to himself, mainly because Jesus is the one who uses the colt. Also, Jesus frequently refers to himself in the third person form (especially in Luke, as the "Son of Man").

I have always been curious, however, as to who the colt's owner believed "the Lord" to be.